# Como comprar senha digitada com senha criptografada em Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com WordPress e preciso verificar a senha do usuário atual na tela de editar senha, porém estou tendo problemas com a criptografia usada no wordpress. Testei o código abaixo publicado no próprio codex, porem não tive exito.

```
<?php
$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

$password_hashed = '$P$B55D6LjfHDkINU5wF.v2BuuzO0/XPk/';
$plain_password = 'test';

if($wp_hasher->CheckPassword($plain_password, $password_hashed)) {
    echo "YES, Matched";
} else {
    echo "No, Wrong Password";
}
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito fácil a resolução desse problema, existe uma função no wordpress que facilita muito, segue a baixo:

```
wp_check_password( $password, $hash, $user_id);
```

$password, recebe a senha descriptografada.
$hash, recebe a senha criptografada.
$user_id, no recebe a função do wordpress para pegar o user id.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
// Pega do banco a senha criptografada
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM  wp_users WHERE id=$user_ID" );
foreach ( $result as $page )
{
   // Variável com a hash
   $senhahash = $page->user_pass.'<br/>';

}
$senhadigitada = "suasenha";
$result = wp_check_password($senhadigitada, $senhahash, $user_ID);
if ($result==1){
    echo "sua senha esta correta";
}else{
    echo "Sua Senha esta Incorreta";
}
?>
```

Comment: Com a linha `$senhahash = $page->user_pass.'<br/>';` está dando erro, mude para `$senhahash = $page->user_pass;`